wayland-ivi-extension porting, after switching to ivi-shell, the screen shows nothing
After switching to ivi-shell, the screen is totally black.
I'm trying to porting ivi-shell. I added a recipes to my Yocto project, ivi-shell.so ,ivi-controller.so are build successfully. Then I try to modify /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini as below
[core]
shell=ivi-shell.so
modules=ivi-controller.so
[ivi-shell]
ivi-input-module=ivi-input-controller.so

But when I run weston, nothing showed.
I tried to call layer-add-surfaces -l 1000 -s 2 & & layer-add-surfaces, didn't see error logs
And I tried to call LayerManagerControl get surfaces, found that surface number is 0
Is there any one who can give me a hint/clue ?
Where should I start debugging?
Thanks a lot

Just found out that "EGLWLMockNavigation" can display on screen, but "weston-simple-egl" can't. the first one is wayland-ivi-extension example, and 2nd one is wayland example. which implies that they might be not compatible..., I will check the version of them...

OK, I compared the source code of weston-simple-touch and EGLWLMockNavigation.
weston-simple-touch operate surface directly through xdg, so I'm wondering maybe xdg can not work with ivi-shell.
then I found this: XDG Support for ivi-shell: ivi-id-agent
https://github.com/COVESA/wayland-ivi-extension/pull/103
Apparently I miss something in weston.ini

[desktop-app-default]
default-surface-id=2000000
default-surface-id-max=2001000
[ivi-shell]
ivi-id-agent-module=ivi-id-agent.so

problem solved...

Hey, since you have already worked woth the extension module. Can this be used for my application where i need two applications, the base is the browser and on top of that i need a menu that will take half the screen size.
I need to switch between menu and browser based on commands.
Any help in building this module and my specific application will be highly appreciated.

If you're using Yocto, so you can just find a recipe here:
https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/meta-agl/blob/master/meta-ivi-common/recipes-graphics/wayland/wayland-ivi-extension_1.13.0.bb
here is command sample you can set the layer order or visibility
https://developer.nvidia.com/docs/drive/drive-os/6.0.6/public/drive-os-linux-sdk/common/topics/window_system_stub/TostartWeston-simple-eglwithivi-shelland99.html
